# Installing pip on ArcGIS Python Installation?

Tags: arcpy, python, installation, pip

I have a problem installing `pip` on my Windows Server 2016 on ArcGIS 10.2 Python installation. Actually, I want to install `requests` package and I want to install it through `pip`.

I have downloaded get-pip.py and tried to run it on my server. But I faced these error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pip
c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\tmpuxaleu\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:354: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\tmpuxaleu\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\tmpuxaleu\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\tmpuxaleu\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\tmpuxaleu\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\tmpuxaleu\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\tmpuxaleu\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

Is there any suggestion on installing `pip` or `requests`?

python: 2.7.3
ArcGIS: 10.2
OS: Windows Server 2016 or Windows 10

Comment: I doubt this can work with such an ancient build of Python (which is what the error said). Since 10.2 is a handful of months from retirement, upgrading to 10.4.1, 10.5.1 or 10.6.1 should give you a more stable Python (and ArcGIS, too).

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests  for a zip file or https://pypi.org/project/requests/#files for a whl file.  Something like python ./setup.py works. Just had this problem 2 weeks ago for requests.

Comment: Upgrade ArcGIS if possible. I understand if you can't though. We had this issue in our corporate environment where we're stuck on 10.2. Our IT department upgraded our ArcGIS python 2.7 to the latest point release (2.7.13 at that time I think) with no ArcGIS related issues afterwards.